# Python text based game inventory and exit not working

Tags: python

I am very new with Python and having issues with a text based game. Specifically, I cannot seem to get the 'exit' and 'pick up [item]' user inputs to register and, well, DO what the user is saying.
For the pick up item I had it working if a user just put in "pick up" (now even that isn't functioning), but I need it to work when I enter 'pick up [item]'
I tried

```
    elif command == 'pick up '+ current_item
```

and

```
    elif command == 'pick up {}'.format(current_item)
```

and

```
    elif command == f'pick up {current_item}'
```

And a whole bunch of other ways that probably make no sense (obviously).
Thank you all so much!

```
def instructions():
    print('Welcome to Grizom''s Greed: A Dragon Adventure Game')
    print('--------------')
    print('To slay Grizom, collect all pieces of the legendary')
    print('crossbow and make your way to the cave below the castle.')
    print('If you enter the cave before you have reforged the weapon')
    print('you are sure to perish.')
    print('Use the cardinal directions - North, South, East, and West to')
    print('navigate the land and use "Pick up [item name]" to get item.')
    print('Enter "Exit" to quit.')
    print('--------------')


rooms = {
    'Drawbridge': {'South': 'Main Courtyard', 'East': 'Stables', 'Item': 'Lever'},
    'Main Courtyard': {'South': 'Training Grounds', 'North': 'Drawbridge', 'West': 'Serene Lake',
                       'East': 'Castle Main Hall', 'Item': 'Bolt'},
    'Stables': {'West': 'Drawbridge', 'Item': 'Trigger'},
    'Serene Lake': {'East': 'Main Courtyard', 'Item': 'Gear'},
    'Castle Main Hall': {'North': 'Music Room', 'West': 'Main Courtyard', 'Item': 'Bow'},
    'Music Room': {'South': 'Castle Main Hall', 'Item': 'Bow String'},
    'Training Grounds':  {'North': 'Main Courtyard', 'East': 'Cave', 'Item': 'Stock'},
}

directions: set[str] = {'North', 'South', 'East', 'West', 'Exit', 'north', 'east', 'west', 'south', 'exit'}
# user instructions
instructions()


# main loop def
def main():
    location = 'Drawbridge'
    inventory = []

    def show_status():
        print('')
        print(f'You are currently at the {location}')
        print(f'You currently have:', *inventory, sep='-')
        if rooms[location]['Item'] in inventory:
            print('This room is empty.')
        else:
            print(f'You see a ' + rooms[location]['Item'])

    while True:
        show_status()
        possible_moves = rooms.get(location, {})
        current_item = rooms[location]['Item']
        command = input('\nPlease enter a direction or take an available item: \n').strip().lower().capitalize()
        if command in directions:
            if command not in rooms[location]:
                print('You cannot go that way')
            elif command in possible_moves:
                location = possible_moves.get(command, location)
                if location == 'Cave':
                    if len(inventory) != 7:
                        print('Against all advice and reason, you have entered the cave without the crossbow.')
                        print('You did not survive. Game Over')
                        break
                    else:
                        print('With the legendary crossbow at your side,')
                        print('You have slayed Grizom. Congratulations!')
                        break
        elif command == 'exit':
            print('Thank you for playing')
            break
        elif command == 'pick up {}'.format(current_item):
            if current_item not in inventory:
                print('You picked up the ' + current_item, 'and added it to your inventory.')
                inventory.append(current_item)
            elif current_item in inventory:
                print('You already have this item.')
            else:
                print('No items available.')
        else:
            print('Invalid input')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

You have two main issues:

1. The capitalization of your input does not match the capitalization of the commands in your program.
2. You have "exit" in your directions set, which means you never reach the check for the exit command.

## Capitalization

You format your input using the following code:

```
command = input('\nPlease enter a direction or take an available item: \n').strip().lower().capitalize()
```

The `.strip().lower().capitalize()` means that input like "pick up lever" is converted to "Pick up lever". However, your code is checking for lower-case "pick up" and upper-case "Lever":

```py
'Drawbridge': {'South': 'Main Courtyard', 'East': 'Stables', 'Item': 'Lever'},
```

```py
elif command == 'pick up {}'.format(current_item):
```

To get it to work as expected, you need to make sure the capitalization matches.

## Exit

You have "Exit" in your directions set:

```py
directions: set[str] = {'North', 'South', 'East', 'West', 'Exit', 'north', 'east', 'west', 'south', 'exit'}
```

This means that if your command is "Exit", the code `command in directions` will evaluate to True, and your program will enter the following if statement:

```py
if command in directions:
```

This means that the statement

```py
elif command == 'exit':
```

will never be reached. (And it is also the wrong capitalization.)

You can't have "Exit" as both a direction and a command to quit the game. You need to choose which one you want it to mean.

## Fixed code

I switched your commands, directions and items to lower case, removed `.capitalize()` from your input formatting, and removed "Exit" from the directions set. This should make your game behave more as expected.

```py
def instructions():
    print('Welcome to Grizom\'s Greed: A Dragon Adventure Game')
    print('--------------')
    print('To slay Grizom, collect all pieces of the legendary')
    print('crossbow and make your way to the cave below the castle.')
    print('If you enter the cave before you have reforged the weapon')
    print('you are sure to perish.')
    print('Use the cardinal directions - north, south, east, and west to')
    print('navigate the land and use "pick up [item name]" to get item.')
    print('Enter "exit" to quit.')
    print('--------------')


rooms = {
    'Drawbridge': {'south': 'Main Courtyard', 'east': 'Stables', 'Item': 'lever'},
    'Main Courtyard': {'south': 'Training Grounds', 'north': 'Drawbridge', 'west': 'Serene Lake',
                       'east': 'Castle Main Hall', 'Item': 'bolt'},
    'Stables': {'west': 'Drawbridge', 'Item': 'trigger'},
    'Serene Lake': {'east': 'Main Courtyard', 'Item': 'gear'},
    'Castle Main Hall': {'north': 'Music Room', 'west': 'Main Courtyard', 'Item': 'bow'},
    'Music Room': {'south': 'Castle Main Hall', 'Item': 'bow string'},
    'Training Grounds':  {'north': 'Main Courtyard', 'east': 'Cave', 'Item': 'stock'},
}

directions: set[str] = {'north', 'east', 'west', 'south'}
# user instructions
instructions()


# main loop def
def main():
    location = 'Drawbridge'
    inventory = []

    def show_status():
        print('')
        print(f'You are currently at the {location}')
        print(f'You currently have:', *inventory, sep='-')
        if rooms[location]['Item'] in inventory:
            print('This room is empty.')
        else:
            print(f'You see a ' + rooms[location]['Item'])

    while True:
        show_status()
        possible_moves = rooms.get(location, {})
        current_item = rooms[location]['Item']
        command = input('\nPlease enter a direction or take an available item: \n').strip().lower()
        if command in directions:
            if command not in rooms[location]:
                print('You cannot go that way')
            elif command in possible_moves:
                location = possible_moves.get(command, location)
                if location == 'Cave':
                    if len(inventory) != 7:
                        print('Against all advice and reason, you have entered the cave without the crossbow.')
                        print('You did not survive. Game Over')
                        break
                    else:
                        print('With the legendary crossbow at your side,')
                        print('You have slayed Grizom. Congratulations!')
                        break
        elif command == 'exit':
            print('Thank you for playing')
            break
        elif command == 'pick up {}'.format(current_item):
            if current_item not in inventory:
                print('You picked up the ' + current_item, 'and added it to your inventory.')
                inventory.append(current_item)
            elif current_item in inventory:
                print('You already have this item.')
            else:
                print('No items available.')
        else:
            print('Invalid input')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```